# Time Machine backing up my entire system every time

Tags: time-machine

For some time now, every time I run Time Machine, it backs up an insane amount of data and takes several hours.  Most recently, it backed up about 70GB, this being supposedly an incremental backup since the previous backup two weeks earlier.   As recommended by others, I ran sudo tmutil compare to see what was being backed up and it listed my entire system, the summary being:
Added:         70.6G
Removed:       1.4G
Changed:       2.4G

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?  I've had to resort to occasional manual backups because nightly backups were still running the next day.

I am running Mojave 10.14.6, with the Time Machine backups on a Synology NAS DS211j.

Comment: Have you tried using Disk Utility to repair permissions on the drive you're backing up? Are there any other issues you're experiencing?

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but why would permissions be a cause of this?

Comment: Not experiencing any other problems.